# OS X virtualization for software development

Tags: osx, virtualization

I am a OS X user and I work on multiple platforms for which I need multiple dependencies. I want to separate my different development dependency packages in virtual environments so they are all isolated and also can be purged easily later on.

General workflow can be described as follows

1. Create a virtual machine
2. Install dependencies and setup work environment (preferably from a config file)
3. Do whatever you want in this environment
4. Purge virtual machine

In Linux we have LXC Containers which can do this thing I guess (never used it but will surely try). May be that's similar thing. May be not. I have used Vagrant which is exactly what am I looking for but for OS X. Please suggest me if do you know of any technology that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Fusion, Virtualbox and Parallels Desktop can all nicely virtualize most Linux, Unix and Windows OS's. Virtualbox is a free option.

Comment: I could not install OSX Lion from recovery partition to  VirtualBox. I would say it requires some work than to get it installed out of the box.